# Adding HttpHeaders to http.get() in Angular 8.1.3 fails to hit API endpoint

Tags: angular, http-headers, http-get

I am using Angular 8.1.3 to perform an HTTP GET to a RESTful API endpoint:

```
export class AnalysisService {

  private analysisUrl = 'https://localhost:44367/api/analysis';  // URL to web api

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'apiKey': 'xxxxx' })
  };

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) { }

  /** GET analysis by id. Will 404 if id not found */
  getAnalysis(id: number): Observable<PresentedAnalysis> {

    const url = `${this.analysisUrl}/${id}`;
    console.log('url: ' + url);

    return this.http.get<PresentedAnalysis>(url, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`fetched analysis id=${id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<PresentedAnalysis>(`getAnalysis id=${id}`))
    );
  }
```

This code works fine if I remove this.httpOptions from the http.get() parameter list -- it hits my breakpoint on my API endpoint.  However, when I include this.httpOptions in the http.get() call, my breakpoint is not hit, and the following is logged to the Chrome console:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you try adding Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * these headers along with your apiKey

Comment: @Ravi, I changed it to this but still getting same errors:

  httpOptions = {

    headers: new HttpHeaders({

      'apiKey': '6839F78B-E996-42E1-86B9-12169FD37A86'

      , 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'

      , 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS'

      , 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'

    })

  };

Comment: @MarkNugentthe CORS policy should be handled at the server side, make sure you have correct configuration  of CORS also can you post your cors config here the way you send it seems odd  `headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'apiKey': 'xxxxx' })` it maybe something like `headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'xxxxx' })` or `headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxx' })`

Comment: `httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'apiKey': 'xxxxx' })
  };` is your api key and without this option sets how can you access your api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this.  My angular app is on 4200 and my ASP.NET Core API is on port 44367 -- hence the CORS issues.

I followed this wonderful post by Rick Strahl to configure CORS on my API for when environment == development: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/sep/26/aspnet-core-and-cors-gotchas

Then I added the API key to the GET request in my Angular service as shown below:

```
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Basic NjgzOUY3OEItRTk5Ni00MkUxLTg2QjktMTIxNjlGRDM3QTg2Og==',//todo don't hardcode
    })
  };
```

Works now!  Thanks for the pointers everyone.

Answer (score 1):

As @JoelJoseph answered, the CORS policy should be handled at the server side. Also the headers which your server anticipate might also vary. Most API endpoints accept the 'Authorization' header for authentication purposes where the header value should prefix with 'Bearer '. The CORS error might also occur if the server doesn't allow certain headers, in your case 'apiKey'. Kindly verify the allowed headers for the api.